# Can dgesvd in LAPACK be used for economy-size SVD computation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab, lapack, svd

I have a rectangular matrix, `X`, of size `50×4000`, where `m=50` and `n=4000`. As can be seen, `m < n`. I need to compute the economy size singular value decomposition (SVD). MATLAB has a [built-in function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html) to perform this task:

> `[ U, S, V ] = svd( X, 'econ' )` also produces the "economy size" decomposition. If `X` is `m`-by-`n` with `m >= n`, then it is equivalent to `svd( X, 0 )`. For `m < n`, only the first `m` columns of `V` are computed and `S` is `m`-by-`m`.

I read the [documentation of LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/PAPERS/crc-lapack-handbook.pdf) library for `xgesvd` and it says.

> ```
> CALL SGESVD( JOBU, JOBVT, M, N, A, LDA, S, U, LDU, VT, LDVT, WORK, LWORK, INFO )
> ```
>
> Input to `SGESVD`:
>
> `JOBU`: Specifies options for computing all or part of the left singular vectors `U`:
>
> = `'A'`, all `M` columns of `U` are returned in the array `U`:
>
> = `'S'`, the first `min(M,N)` columns of `U` are returned;
>
> = `'O'`, the first `min(M,N)` columns of `U` are overwritten on the array `A`;
>
> = `'N'`, no left singular vectors are computed. Note that `JOBVT` and `JOBU` cannot both be `'O'`.

May I gently ask the community whether setting `JOBU = 'S'` or `JOBU = 'O'` in `dgesvd` is equivalent to use MATLAB `svd( X, 'econ')`? If so, having an example code would be great. I would like to also mention that the entries of my original matrix, `X`, is no longer needed after SVD computation and can be replaced with the output of the function. Thank you very much.

Comment: This submission allows you to call Matlab-supplied LAPACK routines http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16777-lapack. You can check that those options produce the same result as the call to the builtin `svd()`. More info on math libraries packaged with Matlab at http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/math-libraries-version-info-upgrade